# Edit permissions to item author

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am working on SharePoint lists and want to give access to item owners to edit them in a workflow without giving permanent edit permissions.

I have access list in grid view and edit items through auto edit button.

Comment: Can you be more specific, or provide some scenario to get clear idea of what you need?

Comment: users dont have the permissions to edit and in a specific list we have to give them edit and delete permissions for all those items which are added by them.

Comment: So Scenario is, you have list where permissions are not inherited, so at site level users don't have edit access, but on list they have edit access, Once the create an item you want to remove their edit permissions, Correct me if I am wrong in interpreting your question

Comment: permissions are inherited and i want to give edit and delete permissions to user for those items only which are created by them only.

Comment: Ok, so only Creator of item should be able to edit, and no-one else.

Comment: Yes, other than those who have who have admin permissions only Creator can edit or delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create SharePoint Designer workflow.
2. Add impersonation Step
3. Select and add "Remove List Item Permissions" action
4. Click on 'these permissions' link
5. Click Add Select the permissions you want to remove then click
   browse, and select all groups which you want to remove access on
   that item.
6. Now Add another action "Add List Item Permissions"
7. Click Add Select the permissions Edit/contribute permisisons, then
   click browse, and select "User who created current item". Click Add,
   Click Ok.
8. In workflow setting mark it to on Item create. Save and publish the
   workflow.
9. Only creator(Author) of item will be able to edit the item.

Comment: done with the steps but didnt get the edit  permissions..

Comment: Can you tell me what you added in step 5? Your Author must have Edit permissions by default, the only challenge is you need to remove access of all other groups/people other than Author for which above steps are sufficient.

Comment: I am glad it helped you.

Comment: can you help me in another issue i want to restrict user from viewing site contents page